# Why does ConTeXt fail to compile when using custom fonts and a bulleted list?

Tags: errors, context, context-mkiv

```
\starttypescript[serif]                    [titillium]
    \definefontsynonym[Serif]            [file:Titillium-Regular]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]            [file:Titillium-Bold]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]            [file:Titillium-Italic]
    \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic]        [file:Titillium-Bold-Italic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[sans]                    [titillium]
    \definefontsynonym[Sans]            [file:Roboto-Regular]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBold]            [file:Roboto-Bold]
    \definefontsynonym[SansItalic]            [file:Roboto-Italic]
    \definefontsynonym[SansBoldItalic]        [file:Roboto-Bold-Italic]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[calligraphy]                [titillium]
    \definefontsynonym[Calligraphy]            [file:Arizonia-Regular]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[handwriting]                [titillium]
    \definefontsynonym[Handwriting]            [file:Pacifico-Regular]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript[titillium]
    \definetypeface[titillium]                [rm][serif][titillium][default]
    \definetypeface[titillium]                [ss][sans][titillium][default]
    \definetypeface[titillium]                [cg][calligraphy][titillium][default]
    \definetypeface[titillium]                [hw][handwriting][titillium][default]
\stoptypescript


\usetypescript[titillium]
\setupbodyfont[titillium, 12pt]

\starttext

    \startitemize
        \item This is an item.
        \item This is another item.
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

When I compile this, it reports:

> tex error       > error on line 38 in file /tmp/test.tex: ! Math error: parameter \Umathquad\displaystyle is not set

- If I change the bulleted list to an enumerated list, e.g. `\startitemize[2]` changed to `\startitemize[n]`, then it compiles fine.
- If I change the bulleted list to default list, e.g. `\startitemize[2]` changed to `\startitemize`, then it similarly fails to compile, reporting the same error.
- If I instead keep the bulleted list, but delete the custom typescript, it compiles fine.
- I tried switching all of the fonts to entirely different fonts, but it similarly failed to compile.

How can I compile the document with custom fonts and a bulleted list?

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE that we can compile to reproduce the problem, as it is, this is just a code snippet. People will be more willing to assist if they don't have to recreate the document (and assume packages, etc) themselves.

Comment: I don't understand. I already provided a minimum working example. I do not add any packages. If I copy that code into a blank file, then compile it, it does not compile, reporting the error I listed.

Comment: The bullet points for the items are taken from the math font but you don’t set one in your document. When you add `\definetypeface [titillium] [mm] [math] [modern] [default]` to your typescripts the error message will disappear.

Comment: but that approach will only load one font file, not two. I just don't see the common sense in it. I would expect to have the two files available, not one.

Comment: When I load Latin Modern as math font two fonts are used in the document which are `latinmodern-math.otf` and `titillium-regular.otf`. When the Titillium font doesn’t exist on your system ConTeXt will use Latin Modern also for the text in the itemize.

Comment: @Metafox unfortunately, and this is with a new file, and fresh texlive, as soon as I add it, it loads only one file. The only viable option I have found, is to load it directly through plain TeX.